# Failed to open TCP connection to repo2.maven.org:80 while making executable war with warbler

Tags: ruby, jruby, warbler

I'm new to warbler and currently trying to learn some basic things.

Running

```sh
warble executable war
```

is creating an error

```sh
Downloading jetty-runner-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
warble aborted!
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Failed to open TCP connection to repo2.maven.org:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. -
connect(2) for "repo2.maven.org" port 80) - http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-runner/9.2.9.v20150224/jetty-runner-9.2.9.v20150224.jar
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/warble:22:in `load'
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/warble:22:in `<main>'
```

I know the reason - there're some security limitations in our corporate network.

I asume I need to use a mirror, but I don't know what and where in warbler configurations I need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding my local mirror link to MAVEN_REPO env variable.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Just to add, for Windows PowerShell users this is an example command: `$env:MAVEN_REPO = "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"` It takes repo URL either from this variable or defaults to hardcoded _http://repo2.maven.org/maven2_

Comment: This worked for me, though I had to add `MAVEN_REPO: "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"` to my .env file. (using dotenv gem)